# Flex jumping label text

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm using Flex to build an app. I've added some states, to switch between them.
And I've made some buttons to change from one to the other state. Each button has a label. When klicking the first button to activate the first state, everthing works fine. When klicking the third button to switch to the third state, the label text in each button begins to jump/toggle and moves back again.

Any idea, how i can fix that ?

```
<mx:LinkButton includeIn="state1,state2,state3,state5,state6"
                   x="20" y="70" width="40" height="40"
                   toolTip="Admins" click="currentState='state2'" id="adminButton" icon="@Embed(source='static/admin.png')" skin="{null}" focusSkin="{null}"/>
```

Comment: Please show some code. We can't possibly show you the way if we're in the dark.

Comment: What might be more helpful to show are the things that you are changing between the states, especially what is changing when you go to the third state. If possible, provide a small app that we can run that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Every state has a list object, which has function that connects to the sqlite database. Nothing else

Comment: I should have also asked you to specify what your states array looks like. Are there only 6 states (states 1-6?) If so, don't bother using the `includeIn="..."` attribute b/c the link button should be included in all states anyway. If there are more than 6, maybe using `excludeFrom` or `excludeIn` (whatever it is) might be better. Just guessing. Again, if you don't show relevant code, all we can do is make guesses :)

Comment: I removed any code and dataprovider from buttons and grids. No change. Still jumping.After removing code, the button icons jumped faster. And after adding again all dataproviders, grids and click handlers, button icon was jumping slow again